# TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [

Tags: predictive-modeling, tensorflow, model-selection

ERROR SUMMARY:

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [
```

BACKGROUND:

I have several features that are histories of user activity. I am trying to predict whether a given user will take an action (represented by a 0 or 1 in my `y_train` list below) based off of their histories of different types of actions. For example, one feature might be `button_A_click_per_day` and the history for a given user would be a vector of button A clicks per day over the past 365 days.

The relevant snippets of my code is as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Build feature columns for classifier
feature_columns = []
for key in X_train:
    col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(
        key=key, 
        shape=max_width,
    )
    feature_columns.append(col)

# Build classifier
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[10, 10],
    n_classes=2,
)
```

And X_train is structured as follows:

```
>>> X_train['<feature_name>']
129     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
...
1294    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
860     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
Name: <feature_name>, Length: 1377, dtype: object
```

My train input function is as follows:

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).repeat(count=None).batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Finally, when issuing the following command...

```
classifier.train(
    # input_fn is a fn that takes not arguments and returns an iterator.
    input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(X_train, y_train, batch_size=100),
    steps=1000,
)
```

I get the error:

```
~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
     63   else:
     64     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
---> 65                     (bytes_or_text,))
     66 
     67 

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [0.0, 0.0, 0...
```

MY QUESTIONS:

1. Do you know what I'm doing wrong to get this error?
2. Is there a better way to model features that are histories?

Comment: have you tried to specify the data type explicitly?

Comment: I figured the default data type of `tf.float32` would be correct since each item in the list is a float and since I used an integer `max_width` for `shape`.

Comment: So now your dtype is `tf.float32` and still getting the same error?

Comment: Correct. Still getting error.

Comment: is that your entire code?

Comment: No its not. I posted what I believed to be enough to understand the goal I am trying to achieve.

Comment: did you get any solution.. I am also facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a built-in function for `train_input_fn` instead of writing your own. For example:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": np.array(training_set.data)},
    y=np.array(training_set.target),
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
```

There is a complete example in the TensorFlow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/get_started/estimator#fit_the_dnnclassifier_to_the_iris_training_data).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause was incorrect type `decimal` for some column; fixed by using instead `float`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar experience, solved by calling `pd.Series#tolist()` apparently.
Here is a whole example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
def get_dataset():
    data = [['Tom', 'M', 95], ['Jerry', 'M', 96], ['Tonny', 'M', 97], ['Lisa', 'F', 98]]
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['name', 'gender', 'score'])
    labels = dataframe.pop('score')
    features = dict()
    # call `pd.Series#tolist()` apparently
    for col_name in dataframe.columns:
        features[col_name] = dataframe[col_name].tolist()
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
    dataset=dataset.batch(2)
    return dataset

dataset=get_dataset()
features,labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([features,labels]))
    print(sess.run([features,labels]))
"""
[({'name': array([b'Tom', b'Jerry'], dtype=object), 'gender': array([b'M', b'M'], dtype=object)}, array([95, 96], dtype=int64))]
[({'name': array([b'Tonny', b'Lisa'], dtype=object), 'gender': array([b'M', b'F'], dtype=object)}, array([97, 98], dtype=int64))]
"""
```